# derived table in subquery can't access main table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Let's say I want to load posts by id with 3 last comment ids for each post.
Natively I wrote this query:

```
select id, (select group_concat(id) from 
  (select id from comments where post_id = posts.id
   order by created_on desc limit 3) ids)
from posts where id in (1,2,3)
```

However, mysql yells with `Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'where clause'`.
I managed to make it work with join, group by and
`substring_index(group_concat(comments.id order by created_on DESC),",",2)`, but it's very slow when there are many comments.

Is there any better option?

Comment: is column `id` exists in the `posts` table?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes, of course

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the query without the derived table:

```
select id, (select group_concat(id) 
    from comments where post_id = posts.id
    order by created_on desc limit 3)
from posts where id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: It won't work. group_concat(id) will take ALL rows and limit won't be relevant .

Comment: `select group_concat(id) from posts where id in (1,2,3) limit 1;`
renders: "1,2,3"